# Java reference and new keyword

Tags: java, oop, abstract

I'm writing a simple chessboard while learning Java and come up with the following question:

I have abstract class `ChessPiece` and classes like `King`, `Queen`, `Rook` etc. which all extend `ChessPiece`.

And I have a 2D array of ChessPiece for the chessboard.

```
public ChessPiece myChessBoard[][] = new ChessPiece[8][8];
```

Then I make my chess pieces like this:

```
ChessPiece aPiece = new Rook();
```

And put it on myChessBoard so I can find it:

```
myChessBoard[0][0] = aPiece;
```

Same goes for other pieces...

My question is when I do this `public ChessPiece myChessBoard[][] = new ChessPiece[8][8];`

in my first step, I used new keyword and allocated 8*8 = 64 ChessPiece objects right? But I did it again when writing `ChessPiece aPiece = new Rook();` I feel stuff in myChessBoard such as myChessBoard[0][0] don't need to be allocated since it's just a reference and don't need that much space as a real chess piece like `new Rook()`.

In short I feel I only need to allocate 32 chess pieces with new keyword (32 pieces on a chessboard) instead of 32 + 64 = 96 chess pieces.

I might have confused some basic concept in Java, please help.

Edit:

`myChessBoard[][] = new ChessPiece[8][8]` here I used new keyword to create 64 reference without real object. So new keyword doesn't necessarily create new objects, it can also create new references referring to null, right?

that is wrong. "the new keyword in that case is creating a new 2D array Object" thanks to accepted answer.

Comment: you are instantiating the abstract class?

Comment: @user2837260 no, I'm not. The only abstract class is `ChessPiece`

Comment: `new ChessPiece[8][8];` ??

Comment: @user2837260 the answers below just explained it. Your question is also enlightening too. :)

Comment: @user2837260: creating an array to hold concrete instances of some abstract class makes a lot of sense, actually.

Comment: @afk5min "concrete instances of some abstract class"?? what do you mean?? isn't that wrong?

Comment: @Arch1tect: each instance of any non-abstract subclass of an abstract class A counts as a concrete instance of A. This includes instances of normal child classes, instances of anonymous subclasses (defined as `new A() { [overridden abstract methods] }`), etc

Comment: @afk5min thank you! I didn't know the phrase concrete instance before..I thought u mean instance of abstract class itself so I thought that's wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you're doing with this `public ChessPiece myChessBoard[][] = new ChessPiece[8][8];` is initializing a new game board.  The game board has 64 squares (each square represented by a 2D index value), not 64 chess pieces.  So each square can be given a chess piece value like `myChessBoard[0][0] = new Rook();`

```
// or to give your pieces references
Knight blackKnight1 = new Knight();
myChessBoard[0][1] = blackKnight1;

Bishop blackBishop1 = new Bishop();
myChessBoard[0][2] = blackBishop1;

Queen blackQueen = new Queen();
myChessBoard[0][3] = blackQueen;

// and do the rest with all the other pieces according 
// to their position in the 2d array
```

Comment: so the `new` keyword can also make new reference instead of new objects right?

Comment: Ultimately, creating a new object IS creating a new reference.  I may not be understanding your question correctly.

Comment: I mean `myChessBoard[][] = new ChessPiece[8][8]` here I used `new` keyword to create 64 reference without real object.

Comment: the `new` keyword in that case is creating a new 2D array Object. I don't see why you want to change that reference.  The chessboard is Not a `chessPiece` Object, it's any array to hold objects of a `ChessPiece` type.  The two reall have noting to do with each other, except that the array MUST hold objects of a `ChessPiece` type

Comment: `new ChessPiece[8][8]` doesn't create 64 `ChessPiece` object instances. It only creates ONE instance of an `array` to hold objects.

Comment: oh, so `new` is creating a 2D array object, that makes sense now. I understand it doesn't create 64 ChessPiece object instances. I didn't realize a 2D array itself is an object..

Comment: Yes! you got it. Please accept answer if this answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

When doing `public ChessPiece myChessBoard[][] = new ChessPiece[8][8];` you did not create a single `ChessPiece`. You only created an Array which is capable of having a reference to 64 ChessPieces.

All references will initially be `null` and you have to set them like `myChessBoard[1][4] = new Rook()`

So there is no need to worry.

I assume your ChessPiece class is abstract anyway, so it is impossible for Java to create a ChessPiece anyway.

But one more point: Java has automatic garbage collection. So even in case you do create some unnecessary objects sometimes, the garbage collector will get rid of it pretty quickly. Don't optimize prematurely. Every computer nowadays can handle 96 or 32 objects and there won't be any noticable difference.

Comment: so the new keyword can also make new reference instead of new objects right?

Comment: It is basically like a pointer. You create a new Object and have a pointer/reference to that object form now on to work with. In Java, basically everything is a reference. Do not confuse this with C++ for example. :)

Answer (score 1):

No.  Writing `new ChessPiece[8][8]` does NOT allocate 64 `ChessPiece` objects.  It only creates an array, with 64 null references in it.  You need to make the `ChessPiece` objects separately, which is what you're doing.

Note that many OOP languages (in particular, C++) work differently in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

`public ChessPiece myChessBoard[][] = new ChessPiece[8][8]` is an array allocation statement. It does **not** allocate 64 new `ChessPiece` objects, but a two dimensional array containing 8*8=64 references to `ChessPiece`s, most of which are `null`. Only wen populating each individual square do you actually create a new `ChessPiece` object.

Having said that, you do have a point, and this allocation policy does seem somewhat wasteful. My suggestion to you, since this is a learning project - hide the chessboard implementation in its own class (e.g., `ChessBoard`), which for now will contain your two dimensional array. Once you've got everything else working to your satisfaction, you can go back and optimize the memory consumption of `ChessBoard`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `ChessPiece myChessBoard[][] = new ChessPiece[8][8];`, you're not instantiating any `ChessPiece` objects. You're just creating a 2D array that can hold them. To give a real-life analogy, when you buy plastic containers to hold leftover food, they don't come with food in them- you put that into the containers later.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the arrays, you simply allocate the storage cells that start of as nulls, but can also be used to store chess pieces later, and you create 64 of these. No chess pieces so far. Those still need to get created separately.

Suppose you've built a prison with 10,000 cells. That's great in itself, but you still have to find 10,000 prisoners to populate it.